# timout command is not timing out

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, timeout

I have a `timeout` command that is not timing out.

```
user@db:~$ ps aux | grep 'timeout'
user       4979  0.0  0.0   4440   628 pts/144  S+   18:52   0:00 sh -c timeout 16 mycommand
user       4980  0.0  0.0  11716   680 pts/144  S    18:52   0:00 timeout 16 mycommand
```

---

```
user@db:~$ ps -p 4980 -o etime=
02:29:16
```

A conundrum for me. This is the exact opposite of what I need to happen, and I am not sure the best place to begin to troubleshoot this problem. I do not know much of the lower level system stuff in *nix systems.

I would like to know

> what is the best approach to troubleshooting a hanging command on a *nix system?
>
> Is there a log or other system info from which I can gather valuable information?
>
> Is there another solid approach to running a command with a time out before it is sent a term signal?
>
> plus all other relevant info...

Also I realize this could be a situation with 'mycommand', so I will note the the actual command being used is a `ffmpeg` command.

Also note that `timeout` works as expected, most of the time.

Comment: You could try tracing it with `strace -p 4980` to see what it's doing.

Comment: @Celada `sudo strace -p 4980` gets this output : 
`Process 4980 attached - interrupt to quit
wait4(4981,`
I am looking up `wait4` now...

Comment: So it's waiting for the subprocess to finish. My guess is that it already tried to kill it but the subprocess ignored the termination signal (`SIGTERM`). In that case, `timeout` just keeps waiting for it unless you give it the `-k` option to force it to kill the child (with `SIGKILL`). Do you know if `mycommand` sets itself up to ignore `SIGTERM`?

Comment: @Celada `mycommand` is actually `ffmpeg` and it will generally respond by ending the process when using the signal `SIGTERM`, but perhaps `-k` is a solution.

Comment: for my case I decided to use the the `--signal=SIGNAL` switch for `timeout` and set the signal to `SIGKILL`.